# Can a same disk be temp for windows and linux?

Tags: linux, windows, ssd, virtual-memory, temporary-files

Is it possible to make a SSD be temp and virtual memory for both windows and linux, without wasting half of the size for the other OS, and be SSD-friendly?

Comment: Did you mean the swap partition or the tmpfs (/tmp, /run)?

Comment: This mat be possible but would be very fiddly (and slow to start) as you would need to get each IS to reformat the partition on startup. Im sure thus could be gacjed into Linux, not so sure on Windows.

Comment: @davidgo If it's slow while starting then it seems not SSD friendly?

Comment: @Biswapriyo /tmp and /swap, fine if a hard separation required

Comment: @l4m2 It depends how you define SSD frienfly. Im not sure such a concept is relevant as SSDs have more write cycles then most people think, you have decided to put swap on an SSD anyway, so the additional wear on the drive is not _that_ much - as only the indexing is rewritten, not the whole partition.

Comment: @davidgo For temp files friendly should mean no unnecessary erase when space is enough(but may have write for enough times) and averaged usage of disk, which looks possible. If I delete everything temp when starting either os, will it show only half of avaliable space but allow disk averaged used?

Comment: This is probably possible for temp files (at least in linux), but swap is a very different matter.